# data.table: find number of times unique id matches element in vector

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a data.table solution for this problem. I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)

codes1 <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
codes2 <- c("B1", "B2", "B3")
codes3 <- c("C1", "C2", "C3")

data <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4),
  code = c("A1","A3", "B1", "A2", "B2","A1","B2","C1")
)
```

I wish to count, for each unique id, number of times `data$code` matches an element in vectors `codes1`,`codes2`, and `codes3`, counting only once for a match in each vector. I wish to end up with the following:

```
data_want <- data.table(
  id = c(1,2,3,4),
  match = c(1,1,2,3)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `codes` vectors in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, after grouping by 'id', then check whether `any` of the elements are `%in%` the 'code' column, `Reduce` the `list` of logical vectors to integer by adding (`+` - `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
library(data.table)
data[, .(match = Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(codes1, codes2, codes3), 
    \(x) any(x %in% code)))), by =  id]
```

-output

```
      id match
   <num> <int>
1:     1     1
2:     2     1
3:     3     2
4:     4     3
```

Comment: It throws an error for me: Error: unexpected input in:
"data[, .(match = Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(codes1, codes2, codes3), 
                                    \"

Comment: @epiNS, can you change the `\(x)` to `function(x)` (in case you have an older R version).  Also, there is either backquote or quotes around the `+` symbol